# Save tuple in a list into a new file

Tags: python, pandas, file-handling

I am saving a tuple into a list (result) with the code below:

```
result.append((a,b,c,values))
```

Now result contains values in the format below:

```
[(100,200,150,33),(210,320,150,56),.....]
```

How do i write it into a file so that the results will be stored in the format below:

```
1. 100,200,150,33
2. 210,320,150,56
..................
```

Comment: I am not able to write a new file with the pandas method

Comment: Why not? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, it just didnt create the outfile.